# Is GTK+ supported on Ubuntu for phones

Tags: application-development, gtk, ubuntu-touch

I wondered if GTK UI library would be supported on Ubuntu phone and tablet ?

I know the SDK for mobile encourage QML/QT but will it be still possible to develop apps for phones, and especially tablets, with GTK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only Qt/QML and HTML5 will be supported, at least at first.  Gtk might *work*, but it won't get support if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when you dock the phone, it's possible to display desktop apps, so GTK is not supported on mobile screen-size, but the library is still here so that you can run desktop apps when a big screen is avaible. Is that right ?

Comment: Jecimi, that's the plan. But not yet implemented.